# queue.remove() and bfs need help java

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

Hello I need help understanding the part of the bfs algorithm where I am setting element to queue.remove() and how element is set with a value. If someone can please explain for me that, that would help a lot. thanks.

```
 class bfs
  {
private Queue<Integer> queue;
public bfs()
{
    queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}

public void bfs(int adjacency_matrix[][] , int source)
{
    int number_of_nodes = adjacency_matrix[source].length-1;

    int[] visited = new int[number_of_nodes +1];
    int i, element;
    visited[source] = 1;
    queue.add(source);

    while(!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        element =queue.remove();
        i = element;
        System.out.println(i+"\t");
        while(i<=number_of_nodes)
        {
            if(adjacency_matrix[element][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 0)
            {
                queue.add(i);
                visited[i] = 1;

            }
            i++;


        }}

    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you give a background. What's the use, why you're doing this, and where exactly is the issue in this situation? SO is to answer coding problems, here, you got an algorithm that can potentially work, I haven't tried to make it run because I don't really understand the need since you did not give any...

Comment: sorry for not being clearer. This algorithm works. It reads in a adjacency matrix and all. What I am not understand is how element = queue.remove() is working in the code, like how is it assigning it a value.

Comment: From the Javadoc: `Retrieves and removes the head of this queue. This method differs from poll only in that it throws an exception if this queue is empty.`

Comment: so basically the element is reading in the head of the queue that was being removed. so element and i are the same, until i enters the while loop and increments continuously which updates the visited, etc. so if the head of the queue is source in this case, then source would = element and i for starters then i would increment and then go to the conditional and run through that? is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

queue is a First-In-First-Out data structure, it helps maintain the sequence of the nodes being searched in a graph using bfs - since in bfs, the direct neighbours of the node (let's call it node A) being visited are always enqueued first, they will hence be dequeued(queue.remove() in your case) earlier than the nodes that are not direct neighbours of node A.

In your code, adjacency_matrix is a 2d square array that you used to keep the neighbour relations. **adjacency_matrix[i][j] == 1 means node j is the neighbour to node i.**

**element = queue.remove();** - gives your the current node to be visited

**queue.add(i);** - adds the neighbor of element to the queue so that it can be visited later.

You can visualize it using the following example:

[image]

Comment: so basically the element is reading in the head of the queue that was being removed. so element and i are the same, until i enters the while loop and increments continuously which updates the visited, etc. so if the head of the queue is source in this case, then source would = element and i for starters then i would increment and then go to the conditional and run through that? is that correct?

Comment: To be honest, I feel a bit regretted to show graph and the tables. Why not you add a column in the iteration table I gave you to trace how i is updated? I suggest you to read the bfs wikipedea to understand the bfs concept. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search